# Indentifying different agents in the same queue

Tags: anylogic

This is the problem:

I have two agent populations; "Blue rectangles" and "Red rectangles". Both of these agents go into the same queue. However it is a little hard to know how many red and blue rectangles are in the queue at an arbitraty time T.

Are there some functions/techniques to fetch this?

Would like to e.g. print in the console: "There are N blue rectangles and M red rectangles in the queue."

Comment: Are the agents in the populations of the same agent type or different agent types? e.g. do you have an agent called `Rectangle` and you simply created two populations of the same agent type?

Comment: No the agents are distinct. So I made one agent type for red and one for blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can loop across all agents in your queue and check each by its agent type (assuming that blue and red agents are actually different agent types):

```
for (int i=0; i<myQueue.size(); i++) {
    if (myQueue.get(i) instanceof AgentTypeBlue) {
        // do whatever you want to count blue agents
    } else if (myQueue.get(i) instanceof AgentTypeRed) {
        // do whatever you want to count red agents
    }
}
```

Alternatively, just use the Queue`s "on enter" and "on exit" code boxes to count whenever a blue or red agent enters & leaves (using a variable` countRed`/`countBlue`) as below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would obviously upvote this answer as well, but my reputation does not allow it ufortunately.

Comment: no worries, good question, appreciate the effort :)